# Could you explain what does っていうのは mean here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances

> コンビニっていうのはそんなに複雑な話はしない場所。

I understand the meaning of the sentence well enough but I don't quite get the usage of っていうのは here. I think it's the casual form of ということは which I thought I knew how to use up until now.

If you could give me a hand here, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

っていうのは is the abbreviated form of というのは

Here is an link (in Japanese) to its meaning

> http://www.edewakaru.com/archives/11527328.html
>
> 「〜というのは」意味や内容（ないよう）の説明（せつめい）・定義（ていぎ）を表す文型です。「〜というのは」の後（うし）ろには「〜のことだ」「〜という意味だ」など、よく使われる表現（ひょうげん）がいくつかありますので、一緒（いっしょ）に覚えておきましょう

So it means that you are going to give details on the part preceeding というのは

So if I am not mistaken, the sentence means:

> a combini store is not a place where you have such a complicated conversation

Comment: この「複雑は話はしない」の「話をする」は、a story happens って意味じゃなくて、chat, talk, have a conversation って意味ですよ。  話をする in 複雑な話はしない here in this sentence means "to chat, to talk, to have a conversation", not "a story happens".

Comment: thanks a lot, I have updated my answer